# Create Instance of Generic Type

Tags: c#

I want to build a generic Observable Collection, that load values from the database to its items. In order to assign the values to the property of the item, I want to create an instance of the object. However, I get an error for the Activator.CreateInstance Command: "'T' is a type, which is not valid in the given context"

```
public class ListBase<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private DbTable tab;


    public ListBase()
    {
        tab = DbCatalog.Tables.Where(x => x.ModelObjectType == typeof(T).Name).First();

        LoadValues();
    }

    private void LoadValues()
    {

        foreach (DataRow r in tab.GetValues.Rows)
        {
            T o = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(T); //<-- The (T) at the end throws the error

            var p = o.GetType().GetProperty("xyz_property");

            if (p.PropertyType == typeof(int))
            {
                p.SetValue(o, Convert.ToInt32(r["xyz_fromDB"]));
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `CreateInstance(typeof(T))`

Comment: Works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use: `CreateInstance(typeof(T))`, `typeof` returns an object of class `System.Type` which will work.

There is a difference in C# between a 'Generic' type `T` and an instance of `System.Type`. Activator.CreateInstance requires the latter.

---

Edit: You should generally use [DavidG's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47952199/1383035), it is cleaner. You can use the `Activator` when:

- You can't add a generic constraint for some reason.
- You want to pass arguments to the constructor. (the `new()` constraint implies a parameterless constructor, with the `Activator` you *can* pass parameters.)

Answer (score 10):

There's no need to use `Activator.CreateInstance`, the correct way to do this is to `new` it up like you would any object - but this requires a [`new` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint):

```
public class ListBase<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : new()
{

}
```

And now you can simply do this:

```
T o = new T();
```

Comment: I havent tried it, but wouldn't this create an instance of the collection instead of a new item? How would I assingn the values to to the object?

Comment: No, it's just creating a new `T`. The rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: The line `T o = new T();` gives me the error "C# Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint"

Comment: Like I said in my answer, add the `new` constraint - at the end of the first line.

Comment: You are right - it works fine! Sorry, I was a little quick there. Why is this the correct way, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Firslty, you can see at a glance that you are creating a new object rather than the slightly more obscure `CreateInstance`. Also, it forces the new constraint which means `T` requires a parameterless constructor and will not compile otherwise. With the previous method, you are vulnerable to runtime errors.